# How to validate CSV file for no. of rows and columns?

Tags: csv, vbscript

I am trying to ascertain that the data file that is fed to my app has certain no of columns so that it doesn't fail in the application. Also I want to count number of rows and check that same number of rows is loaded to DB.

I also need to check that each row is containing a same number of columns.

I tried to write it as below but still struggling with the result.

```
Dim objFSO, dataArray, clippedArray
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Create an array out of the CSV

'open the data file
Set oTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\ds\Desktop\Quota\new_file.csv")
Set newFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\ds\Desktop\loginfo.txt")
'make an array from the data file
dataArray = Split(oTextStream.ReadAll, vbNewLine)
'close the data file
oTextStream.Close
WScript.Echo "No. of Rows is " & UBound(dataArray)

For Each strLine In dataArray
    'Now make an array from each line
    clippedArray =  Split(strLine,"|")
    lngHowManyColumns = UBound(clippedArray)
    WScript.Echo UBound(clippedArray)    

Next
WScript.Echo "No. of Columns is " & lngHowManyColumns

WScript.Echo "Done"
```

Edited to make more sense as few experts were not able to understand the question, however it has been already answered below.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "validate"? What are you "not able to achieve"? `UBound(varArray)+1` gives you the number of fields in a row, `UBound(dataArray)+1` gives you the number of lines in the input file. Please describe what isn't working. [Edit] your question to do so.

Comment: updated my question and latest code.

Comment: You still haven't explained what problem you're facing.

Comment: What are you validating, number of columns, number of rows, whether they contain data? What??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep it simple: Loop over the rows, check for field seps **in each row** via Split:

```
Option Explicit

Const csFSpec = "..\data\47261155.csv"
Const csFSep = ","
Const cnCols = 3    ' one less to optimize for UBound()!
Const cnRows = 6    ' one more to optimize for .Line

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oTS : Set oTS = goFS.OpenTextFile(csFSpec)
Dim sL, nC
Do Until oTS.AtEndOfStream
   sL = oTS.ReadLine()
   nC = UBound(Split(sL, csFSep))
   If cnCols <> nC Then
      WScript.Echo "Col Error in line", oTS.Line - 1 & ":", cnCols, "<>", nC, "(" & sL & ")"
   End If
Loop
If cnRows <> oTS.Line Then
   WScript.Echo "Row Error: ", cnRows, "<>", oTS.Line 
End If
oTS.Close
WScript.Echo "no news is good news"
```

output:

```
type ..\data\47261155.csv
1,2,3,4
4,3,2,1
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4


cscript 47261155.vbs
Col Error in line 3: 3 <> 4 (1,2,3,4,5)
Col Error in line 4: 3 <> 2 (1,2,3)
Row Error:  6 <> 7
no news is good news
```

Comment: *"no news **are** good news"* is not English, which is [why I edited the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47262149/2) to make more sense, it was a small edit. The phrase should be ["No news **is** good news"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/No+news+is+good+news)...You can be so petty sometimes!